# Why can't I access the key values in my array of objects in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, onclick, react-props

I am trying to create an app where you can go through a list of recipes and click a recipe to add it to your list of favorites. Currently my app is creating a new card but the card has none of the info that it should i.e. name, or text. Unfortunately you all cant even see the pics which is a whole other issue i will resolve but you can see the other info on each card that I am trying to pass to the favorite list.

Top level app

```
import Favorites from "./Favorites";
import { Menu } from "./Menu";
import { Cards } from "./Cards";

import { useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState([]);
  const [array, setArray] = useState([
    {
      text: "Check 123",
      name: "Lahmacun",
      image: "./src/lahmacun.jpeg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 456",
      name: "Chicken",
      image: "./src/chicken.webp",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 789",
      name: "Veggies",
      image: "./src/vegan.jpeg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Pho",
      image: "./src/pho.jpeg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
  ]);

  const handleLike = (card) => {
    setFavorite((prev) => [...prev, card]);
  };

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Recipes To Try</h1>
      <form className="m-2" action="">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-3 ">
            <label className="form-label pt-2" id="searchBar">
              Find A Recipe
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-7 col-5">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="searchBar"
              placeholder="Search"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-1 col-2">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" id="searchBtn">
              Search
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <Favorites favorite={favorite} />
      <Menu array={array} handleLike={handleLike} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Favorites Component

```
import { Cards } from "./Cards";

export default function Favorites({ favorite }) {
  return (
    <div id="favorites">
      <h1>Favorites</h1>
      {favorite.map((i) => (
        <div className="col col-md mb-3 mb-sm-0" key={i.id}>
          <div className="card">
            <img src={i.image} alt="" className="card-img-top " />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{i.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{i.text}</p>
              <a
                onClick={() => handleLike()}
                href="#"
                className="btn btn-primary"
              >
                Add to Favorites
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Menu Component

```
import { Cards } from "./Cards";

export function Menu({ array, handleLike }) {
  return (
    <div id="menu">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <h3 className="">Ready for Testing</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <Cards array={array} handleLike={handleLike} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Card component

```
export function Cards({ array, handleLike }) {
  return (
    <>
      {array.map((i) => (
        <div className="col col-md mb-3 mb-sm-0" key={i.id}>
          <div className="card">
            <img src={i.image} alt="" className="card-img-top " />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{i.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{i.text}</p>
              <a onClick={handleLike} href="#" className="btn btn-primary">
                Add to Favorites
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your help!

I expected the added card to contain the name, text, id and image but I just got a card with a button.

Comment: As per the answer below, you additionally have another `onClick` inside `Cards` component where you are passing a function but that function (`handleLike`) needs to take an argument `card` so you have to modify it again into `onClick={() => handleLike(i)}`. Other than that if your issue is beyond this bug; create a minimal reproductive code at [React CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your code; it looks like you are calling a function to add a certain recipe as a favorite.
Everything looks correct, but there is a silly mistake in your Favorites.jsx component.

Your function is:

```
 const handleLike = (card) => {
    setFavorite((prev) => [...prev, card]);
  };
```

Look in your function; you are passing an argument, which is "card". But, in your Favourites.jsx component, you are passing nothing but just calling the function.

```
import { Cards } from "./Cards";

export default function Favorites({ favorite }) {
  return (
    <div id="favorites">
      <h1>Favorites</h1>
      {favorite.map((i) => (
        <div className="col col-md mb-3 mb-sm-0" key={i.id}>
          <div className="card">
            <img src={i.image} alt="" className="card-img-top " />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{i.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{i.text}</p>
              <a
                onClick={() => handleLike() // Nothing passed as an argument here.
                }
                href="#"
                className="btn btn-primary"
              >
                Add to Favorites
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, I think you understand the issue.
In your onClick function in Favorite.jsx components

Just pass the argument, which is `i`.

Revised code:

```
{favorite.map((i) => (
  <div className="col col-md mb-3 mb-sm-0" key={i.id}>
    <div className="card">
      {/* ... */}
      <h5 className="card-title">{i.name}</h5>
      <p className="card-text">{i.text}</p>
      <a onClick={() => handleLike(i)} href="#" className="btn btn-primary">
        Add to Favorites
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

I hope this helps. It can happen sometime, so don't worry.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I think you might be onto something with the idea of passing the parameter but when I passed i to the handleLike i got the same result.... Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you provide me with the GitHub URL of this project?